# Extract json data with php doesnt works

Tags: php, json

I have json data like this:

```html
{"result":{"total":19,"hits":[{"keyword":"sidney webb"},{"keyword":"dr webb"}]},"status_msg":"OK","status_code":200,"left_lines":1196851}
```

I need to extract from json only keywords. I try without success with code:

```html
$json = '{"result":{"total":19,"hits":[{"keyword":"sidney webb"},{"keyword":"dr webb"}]},"status_msg":"OK","status_code":200,"left_lines":1196851}';

foreach ($json['result'] as $keywords)
{
    echo $keywords['result']['keyword'];
}
```

Comment: When you say "without success" could you edit your question to include what you do see? What is the output of this example?

Comment: DaveyDaveDavem result was zero - blank screen.

Answer (score 5):

Seems, you forgot to decode the string with `json_decode`. In addition, your likely would to loop over `[result][hits]` and not just `[result]`

```
$json = '{"result":{"total":19,"hits":[{"keyword":"sidney webb"},{"keyword":"dr webb"}]},"status_msg":"OK","status_code":200,"left_lines":1196851}';
$json = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($json['result']['hits'] as $hit)
{
    echo $hit['keyword'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Philipp, works.

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
    $json = '{"result":{"total":19,"hits":[{"keyword":"sidney webb"},{"keyword":"dr webb"}]},"status_msg":"OK","status_code":200,"left_lines":1196851}';
    $jsonp =json_decode($json,TRUE);

    foreach ($jsonp['result'] as $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val) ){
        foreach ($val as $k)
        {
            echo  $k['keyword'];

        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, safin chacko, your code also works.